# Quitting dozens of the same process in OS X Terminal

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, python, process

Whenever I'm testing a python class I'm working on, I initiate and re-initiate python a lot to refresh the updates I make to the code. When I close the Terminal window later, I get a window that says I am about to quit a LOT of running instances of python.

[image]

Is this a bug on terminal's part, or am I really running all those? I Ctrl-Z out of it each time but it always says

```
[8]+  Stopped            Python
```

where the 8 is incremental and often gets into the 20's and 30's. Am I doing something stupid?

Comment: Hi. I will initiate it with `python` and exit with Ctrl-Z.

Comment: Added how to actually quit python to my answer.

Comment: Now don't cause a fuss dear, I'm having python, python, python, python, eggs, bash, python and python. (cue viking chorus)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not *quitting* (or terminating) the program by pressing `Ctrl-Z`, you're suspending it. Press `Ctrl-D` (*end of transmission*) to quit Python.

And after suspending a running process, you're entering `python` or another intermediate launch script to "resume" the program. But this launches a separate instance of the program!

You need to enter either `%n` (with `n` being the number displayed, so e.g. `%8`) to resume the suspended process with job index `n` or `fg` to resume the most recently suspended process.

If you `Ctrl-Z` out and `fg` back in, the index doesn't increase either.

You are actually running tons of separate `python` instances. List them by entering `jobs`.

The `man` page for this is `bash`, as your shell manages these jobs.

Comment: You can also look at the Inspector to see the list of processes for the terminal. **Shell > Show Inspector**

Comment: Just learned you can clear all past jobs with `disown -a`

Comment: @artur sure if you want a ton of processes to continue running. You just disassociate them from your shell, you don't quit them.

Comment: Oh wow okay. Any idea how to re-own them? :P

Comment: @ArturSapek If you did `disown` instead of following the instructions in my post, all you can reasonably do is `kill` them. `ps ax | grep python` will show their process IDs you can then use as arguments to `kill`. Or, if it's a reasonably often rebooted desktop computer, just restart.

Comment: I figured a restart would do it. Your instructions did help though, so thanks